# Ionic Native Toast message not showing when working with modalController

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, toast

I am using [Toast](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/toast/) to show a message. It works fine when it is not toasting a message on top of [ModalController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/). 
So it is probably because toast has a lower z-index.

Things I have tried:
Change the z-index of the ion-modal.(sass showing below)
Use [ToastController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toast/ToastController/).(works in browser, but not on device so I switched to Toast)

```
ion-modal{
    z-index:1 !important;
    .modal-wrapper{
        z-index:1;
    }
    ion-backdrop{
        z-index:2;
    }
}


**********
Your system information:

 ordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: Please share the full .ts and .html files for your modal and parent.

Comment: Sad to say but I fix the problem without fixing it...I decided to try ToastController again when I woke up, so I retested it on a new project and it worked! So I removed all Toast related code and css above from my project. And it is working now!?!!? I have no clue what was preventing ToastController to work initially. Same package was used and same version as well. Thanks @maninak for being here to help. I would delete this post since this has no value to others...

Comment: Good that you thought outside of the box and I'm glad I could help. Don't delete the post, it has value for someone else.

Answer (score 2):

The quirky thing with `z-index` is that it only applies to elements that have it. So if you define a `z-index` on the modal and not the toast as well, it won't affect the latter.

Try applying a `z-index`on the toast that is higher than that of the modal.

Also, always remember that any element with z-index needs to have position either `relative` or `absolute`.

Comment: Do you know the css selector for the toast? Not able to find it since it doesnt display on browser. That's why I was changing the z-index of the ion-modal. And shouldn't toast already have some kind of z-index because it is showing on top of everything else except the modal, maybe I am wrong not sure. Thanks for the tip tho, I will keep look into the z-index.

Comment: Turns out that ionic has those values (at least on their docs website demos): `<ion-toast style="z-index: 20001;">` and `<ion-modal style="z-index: 10000;">`. By the looks of which the toast _should_ be over the modal, but as you say it isn't. I'm stumped.

Comment: Ion-toast sounds like a ionic `ToastController` element, which works fine only on browser but not on android device. The document might be outdated as ion-modal shows `z-index=9999` on my browser.

Comment: Well there it is then! What if you changed that down to something below the `z-index` of your toast? :)

Comment: I think there is a confusion here. Toast is different than ToastController. [Toast](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/toast/) is from cordova plugin, and [ToastController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toast/ToastController/) is from Ionic. With **ToastController**, I am able to show toast on browser even on top of modal, but not on android device. With **Toast**, it is not able to show on browser ( so make it hard for me to find the element);but able to show toast on device, however not able to show on top of modal...(I am like rewriting the question here...)

Comment: On the **browser**, does the *Toast* show up without the modal?

Comment: No, it doesn't, it only shows up on device when there is no modal( I am building a phone application, so it has what I want eventually). I am checking on installing cordova.js so I can **Toast** message on browser and find its z-index. Hope this is caused by z-index.